# php regular expression for spliting string with specific separator

Tags: php, regex

i have a string like this:

```
3000|string-in-unicode
100|string-in-unicode
```

and etc
which regular expression should i use?

Comment: What do you want to do with the regular expression? Just to recognize the string or to extract a part from it? How did you try to do it?

Comment: what expected outcome you want?Is it a single string or two string?Also if it's single string are the texts are in newlines?

Comment: i want extract values in the left and right pipeline but i want clean them to prevent malicious values like scripts and etc. just simple number in the left and simple string in the right.

Comment: @AlivetoDie I really appreciate you, Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a dedicated separator in your string (like the | character), I would suggest you to use `str_split`. It is quite a bit faster than using regular expression. When you have the values, you can perform checks to validate if the values are valid.

and if you must use regexp:

```
$str = '100|string-in-unicode';
preg_match('/(?<int>\d+)\|(?<name>.+)/', $str, $matches);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 100|string-in-unicode
    [int] => 100
    [1] => 100
    [name] => string-in-unicode
    [2] => string-in-unicode
)
```

Comment: Yes, you right. Thanks Jeffrey.

Comment: @AlivetoDie sure..